# LaTeX: code formatted using listings package is a mess if cut'n pasted

Tags: latex, highlight, listings

I'm documenting an install procedure for multiple components in a Linux based solution using LaTeX. For highlighting commands, I use the listings package. 
It has to be possible to copy paste the commands from the PDF but the pasted text is messy. Apparentely at random, spaces are inserted between letters.

I have tried to add and remove features via lstset to no avail. This looks as intended in the PDF

```
\begin{lstlisting}
ldapadd -x -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w DM_PASS -f aci.ldif
\end{lstlisting}
```

but copy paste yields

```
ldapadd −x −D " cn=D i r e c t o r y Manager" −w DM_PASS −f a c i . l d i f
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: See the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/198395/1031244)

Comment: @Das_Geek is right: PDF is not _text_ in that sense :(

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. On import, define a custom style:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=flexible,
    showstringspaces=false
}
```

- `basicstyle` defines the new font. I would avoid `\sffamily` and `\rmfamily` as they do not format `-` correctly.
- `columns = flexible` will solve the spacing problem.
- `showstringspaces` will avoid a problem with the spaces within a string (here `cn=Directory Manager`).

Then, when declaring the listing, do:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
  ldapadd -x -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w DM_PASS -f aci.ldif
\end{lstlisting}
```

Now, the copy pasting works better.